# WPF fast Controls / whatever creation

Tags: wpf, performance

I have a **itemcontrol** that has 3 possible datatemplates.

```
<DataTemplate>

    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock
            FontSize="25"
            FontWeight="Light"
            Margin="0,8,0,5"
            Text="{Binding Name}" >
        </TextBlock>
        <!-- Εδω τα items -->

        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding Preferences}"
            Name="items" >
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=SelectionMode}"
            Value="1" >

            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate"
                TargetName="items"
                Value="{StaticResource SoloSelection}" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=SelectionMode}"
            Value="2" >

            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate"
                TargetName="items"
                Value="{StaticResource MultiSelection}" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=SelectionMode}"
            Value="3" >

            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate"
                TargetName="items"
                Value="{StaticResource MultiQuantitySelection}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>

</DataTemplate>
```

The stuff inside is a wrappanel with some buttons. So virtualization doesnt seem very easy.And i want smooth scrolling. The problem is that although buttons are a border and a textblock  it is SLOW.

I did a test.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var vv = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    // here is the operation that fills the control
    var b = new Button();
    b.Height = 65;
    b.Width = 120;
    b.Content = "Gamiese";
    this.items.Items.Add(b);
}


this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            sw.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        }));
}
```

This takes about 40-50ms at my computer but 200+ms at a slow one. So with all the other stuff and not this simple example it can be as high as 600-900ms. So touch experience can be slow and painful. I blame WPF for this because i did a similar test with QT QML and creation for heavier 200 buttons it was lighting instant and with smooth scrolling. So WPF doesnt perform well out of the box for this. Is there anything i can do ? Even caching buttons doesnt help.Because populating the tree seems to be tha problem. Rendering isnt the problem because scrolling is very fast at all computers..
Custom drawing might solve my problems but why should i do this ?

Comment: Maybe you should post complete, compilable code for both tests; As it stands, on the WPF side you're talking about an `ItemControl`, you're showing a `DataTemplate` but the demo code is totally unrelated (plain Buttons). With plain Buttons I did not manage to reproduce your issue, I was up to 1000 buttons before I got to 200 ms total time (from constructor call to `ContentRendered`). Also Button is not exactly a light-weight object, trying the same with `TextBlock` allows me to create 2500 objects in 200ms total time.

Comment: i will add more details.200 ms is at the slow computer with atom cpu and plain buttons.I noticed that when i made a custom control , OnRender is called even control is not visible

Comment: you should provide your StaticResources and maybe some futher infos about what you are doing. It looks like you are using mvvm because of your binding but we cant help you if we didn't get your VM or what ever you bind to

Comment: additional the View elements will normally created on the fly if the element comes into View and also the Views will get reused if i remind correctly. If you see in a `ListBox` only 3 items there will be only 3 View elements doesn't matter how much elements in your `ItemsSource`

Comment: @Parhs: Are you using some effects like `OpacityMask` or `DropShadow`?

Comment: 1.25ms/button? sounds reasonable to me. chances are your UI design needs to be reworked altogether - nobody cares to see 150 buttons on their screen anyway (are you implementing MineSweeper?)

Comment: it isnt 150 buttons but it is a pos application so it could be as many as 50 .

Answer (score 1):

Your UI scheme probably needs to be reworked. From what I gather from your post (which is NOT very clear) you're trying to stack up a bunch of buttons in a stackpanel.

Your tests on a slow machine show 1.25ms/button, which sounds pretty acceptable... unless you're abusing the system.

A better approach would be to make yourself a ListView and add your items of interest as items, this way you'd be letting ListView's virtualization determine when to instantiate UI elements.

Your test suggests you're trying to pile up over 9000 pixels hight of buttons, which doesn't make sense even for extra-large screen with extra-high resolution.

Comment: i dont need that many but they could be 70 buttons for POS application.so it can be slow on atom cpu

Comment: I'm building a POS too and I can tell you for sure you don't need 70 buttons shown at once

Comment: some have 70 preferences for example displayed as buttons.Other programs i have seen have MORE in a single screen.

Comment: Just because someone does that doesn't mean it's right. There was once a phone company that was proud to have a full keyboard, since obliterated by companies that make phones with less than 10 buttons. For a better advice post this question on UX without the technical part, ask how to organize the interface so it doesn't require 70 buttons, you'll be surprised.